# How to import products with multiple descriptions into magento

Tags: magento, import

I am importing products from a 3rd party database into my magento site.  I have found a great tutorial online for doing this in PHP.

However, the tutorial does not describe how to assign multiple descriptions to a single product based on the store.

In my example I have a product that has both an english and french description.  One for my French store and one for the english, how can I import both into magento.

I also need to do this for the title, urlkey and have different categories assigned per store.

Here is the code given on the tutorial.

```
<?php
require_once('/path/to/magento/app/Mage.php');
umask(0);

// Set an Admin Session
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'adminhtml'));
$userModel = Mage::getModel('admin/user');
$userModel->setUserId(1);
$session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
$session->setUser($userModel);
$session->setAcl(Mage::getResourceModel('admin/acl')->loadAcl());

// Then we see if the product exists already, by SKU since that is unique to each    product
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->loadByAttribute('sku',$_product['sku']);

if(!$product){
// product does not exist so we will be creating a new one.

$product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();

$product->setTypeId('simple');
$product->setWeight(1.0000);
$product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
$product->setStatus(1);
$product->setSku('UNIQUESKUHERE');
$product->setTaxClassId(0);
$product->setWebsiteIDs(array(0)); // your website ids
$product->setStoreIDs(array(0));  // your store ids
$product->setStockData(array(
    'is_in_stock' => 1,
    'qty' => 99999,
    'manage_stock' => 0,
));
}

// set the rest of the product information here that can be set on either new/update
$product->setAttributeSetId(9); // the product attribute set to use
$product->setName('Product Title');
$product->setCategoryIds(array(0,1,2,3)); // array of categories it will relate to
$product->setDescription('Description');
$product->setShortDescription('Short Description');
$product->setPrice(9.99);

// set the product images as such
// $image is a full path to the image. I found it to only work when I put all the images I wanted to import into the {magento_path}/media/catalog/products - I just created my own folder called import and it read from those images on import.
$image = '/path/to/magento/media/catalog/products/import/image.jpg';

$product->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ()));
$product->addImageToMediaGallery ($image, array ('image'), false, false);
$product->addImageToMediaGallery ($image, array ('small_image'), false, false);
$product->addImageToMediaGallery ($image, array ('thumbnail'), false, false);

// setting custom attributes. for example for a custom attribute called special_attribute
// special_attribute will be used on all examples below for the various attribute types
$product->setSpecialAttribute('value here');

// setting a Yes/No Attribute
$product->setSpecialField(1);

// setting a Selection Attribute
$product->setSpecialAttribute($idOfAttributeOption); //specify the ID of the attribute   option, eg you creteated an option called Blue in special_attribute it was assigned an ID of some number. Use that number.

// setting a Mutli-Selection Attribute
$data['special_attribute'] = '101 , 102 , 103'; // coma separated string of option IDs. As ID , ID (mind the spaces before and after coma, it worked for me like that)
$product->setData($data);

try{
$product->save();
} catch(Exception $e){
echo $e->getMessage();
//handle your error
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually chose magmi to do this job.

Everything is entered into a CSV, if you're importing old data from another system, you need to create this CSV programmatically.

An example of what this CSV should look like is [here](http://hotfile.com/dl/134747928/bbbac3e/export_all_products.csv.html)

To do multiple descriptions for one product, simply copy the row of a product and duplicate it underneath, change the store code field/website field to the code of the site you need a different description for and enter a new description in the description field.

Now when you upload your CSV with Magmi, you'll get one product with 2 or more descriptions associated with the relevant store/website.

Feel free to comment and ask more questions, this was a headache for me and I'd be glad to relieve you of similar frustrations.

Answer (score 3):

[Magmi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/) does that

Answer (score 1):

Are you using websites, stores or store views? This is important as you cannot necessarily set tax/VAT and pricing to 'price points' if you are using store views rather than websites.

```
$product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setWebsiteIds(whatever)->setStoreId(whatever)->load(whatever)
```

You can always use dataflow profiles for this, simply export your products, put in the fields to update and include a 'store' column. Load it back up again and job's a good un.

Comment: Thanks, after thinking about it, I decided to load products using a CSV.  Trouble is in magento 1.6 the categories are specified by name not id.  I have categories with the same name so magento doesn't know which one to put my products under.  This is really frustrating me.  I've tried specifying category ids by creating a category_ids column instead but magento ignored it.